# I am getting this error from apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am getting this error from apache after installing mbstring for phpmyadmin

[Sun Apr 10 15:08:01.486060 2016] [:error] [pid 13360] [client 127.0.0.1:56558] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477

previously phpmyadmin told me i required mbstring so i did sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

now when i go on localhost/phpmyadmin it gives me an error 500

any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bro check out this link. I just added the sudo apt-get install php-gettext, and phpmyadmin works now. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=819521

Answer (score 2):

And
    sudo systemctl reload apache2.service
once php-gettext is installed!